# Finding prime numbers - Calling boolean array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment to finish about finding prime numbers. I have some general questions. I already have method figured it out. I do not need help with the method. Need to know basics like how to initialize and call. Here is the assignment.

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes to learn how to find all prime numbers less than or equal to a given positive integern. Then declare and implement a class named SieveOfEratosthenes.  This class will contain the following data members and methods:

Data members:
      positive integer MAXSIZE //physical size of array
      positive integer n //user input
      1 dimensional Boolean array P

Methods:
      constructor – create array P of size MAXSIZE.
      setP – initialize n and P.
      sieve – find all primes using array P.
      printP – print the primes found

Your main program should use an appropriate menu.

---

Question: What is one dimensional boolean array? Is it anything special compare to assigning boolean array?

Question: How to initialize n and P

```
void setP (int newN, boolean newP[]) {
      n = newN;
      P = newP;
}
```

Is this correct? If so, how do I call P[] from the main method. I know how to call n.

Question: How do I put n into array P[] as far as calling it goes? For example, if n = 100, I can put 1-100 into an array. But how do I call it once user inputs the size n?

Comment: "_What is one dimensional boolean array?_" `boolean[] someArray = new boolean[someLength];` Just a bunch of booleans.

Comment: From user you get N, then make a new array `boolean newP[] = new boolean[N]`. This N now makes your array N elements long and last elem is N-1 (cause you start at 0)

Comment: ok great thanks. Do I create a for loop to put the size N in P[] within setP (initialize) method or finding prime method?